# Can I save a range to a variable?

Tags: python, variables

Is there any way to assign an interval in a variable?

For example

```
my_string = "abcdef"
my_interval = 1:3
print(my_string[my_interval])
```

I wish to return `bc`. However, the second line does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the python builtin function [`slice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) to assign the `slice` to a variable. Your current syntax is not a valid python syntax.

```
>>> my_string = "abcdef"
>>> my_interval = slice(1, 3)
>>> print(my_string[my_interval])
```

Comment: Use `silce()` here is the best choice, but also there's a way without `slice()`: `s = (1, 3); print(my_string[s[0]:s[1]])`.